# I only want to modify one tpl.php for a theme, do I need to copy the base theme?

Tags: theming

I only need to have one tpl.php added to a theme,but the theme I am using is not my own.  If I still want to have this theme as my "base" and then create my own theme with the tpl.php using a theme suggestion I want, how do I get this to work.

I have tried setting the base theme as the default and then creating my own theme with the tpl.php I want and enabling it, but it isn't working. If this is the correct way to do this, what is the minumum needed in the `.info` file and the folder for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimalist amount you need for a subtheme info file are the [2 required keys](https://www.drupal.org/node/171205), `name` & `core`, plus the declared base theme key, `base theme`.

If you a create info file with those keys, copy over the tpl.php (e.g. **page.tpl.php**) from the base theme, modify it, flush caches (to rebuild the theme registry), and use the ***Enable and set default*** from the theme administration page, you should have a working subtheme.

See the d.o. docs on [creating a subtheme](https://www.drupal.org/node/225125) for more info.